# Outside or within remit - should a BDD scenario be created for this user request

Tags: test-design, functional, bdd, user-stories

Given the following overarching purpose (mission statement) for an application:

*In order to help keep a healthy and refreshing sleep regime, or in order to limit computer-related addictive behaviours, computer users can automatically lock their devices for certain befitting times in a tamper-proof manner.*

Would creating a Gherkin feature or scenario for the user request below (and later implementing it to pass) be unfitting and bloating the app or does this request actually fit under the scope of this app somehow?

*Could you please also provide the option to shut down the device on lockdown, not just lock it.*

- If it does fit then how exactly is it linked to the overall value statement?

Comment: are you asking for our opinion about whether the shutdown feature is implied by the mission statement?  Or is this a question about BDD process?

Comment: @user246 Whether the shutdown feature follows from / serves the mission statement. And therefore whether such a feature should be included if wanting to be outside-in value-driven (BDD).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mobile app development, not testing.

Comment: @user246 how is this not about testing? it is a concrete example that helps to elucidate the process of behavior driven development, in particular, how should this case be dealt with when employing this testing framework

Comment: It is an issue that arises during testing, but there is nothing test-specific about deciding whether that shutdown requirement derives from that mission statement.  So this question is not about test testing.

Comment: if you strongly disagree, we can discuss it at http://meta.sqa.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @user246 Thanks for the meta reference, I have raised the issue in http://meta.sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/323/understanding-testing-process-such-as-bdd-through-examples